# PHP POST method into RESTful web service

Tags: php, html, web-services, curl, http-post

The simple thing I want to do is to POST into a RESTful web service using PHP. I have been able to GET the values using PHP, now I want to POST into it. This is the PHP file using curl.

```
<?php
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $url = "http://localhost:8080/WMWS/webresources/entity.userregistration";

    $data = array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password);
    $initializeCurl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($initializeCurl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($initializeCurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($initializeCurl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($initializeCurl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    $response = curl_exec($initializeCurl);
    curl_close($initializeCurl);
?>
```

I am using XAMPP and I have enabled curl in PHP.ini file. Whenever I insert values into the form input of HTML and click the submit button, it only return the PHP code on the browser and does nothing like insertion. How can I handle it?

This is is the HTML file:

```
<body>
    <form action = "posttoxml.php" method = "POST">
        <label for = "username">Username</label>
        <input type = "text" name = "username" />
        <label for = "password">Password</label>
        <input type = "password" name = "password" />
        <button id = "register" name = "register">Register</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: By "it only returns the PHP code", do you mean you see the PHP source code? As in, it's not rendering? Or just a blank page?

Comment: Exactly! it returns the PHP source code on the web page and does not insert.

Comment: My guess is, this happens to all php files, you can try a simple example, create a php file with only <?php phpinfo(); in it an save in so you can see it in a browser. I think something is wrong with the PHP installation provided by xampp

Comment: Ok. thanks. i'll try it out. I have done that. it displayed the phpInfo() content.